# Doesn't display data formatted in FireDAC with SQLite in Delphi 10

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

I'm using TFDQuery from FireDAC with SQLite database, displaying some formatted fields and I'm having problems with "printf" because TFDQuery doesn't display the data in the situation indicated below:

```
// THIS WORKS ON SQLite CONSOLE and doesn't work in Delphi
// With a comma separator it should show "1,234" in SQLite console and it shows "empty data" in Delphi
SELECT printf('%,d', 1234 ) AS val_tot FROM itens;

//THIS DOESN'T WORK FROM THE SQLITE CONSOLE AND SHOWS WRONG DATA IN DELPHI
// With dot separator shows '1234' in Delphi and doesn't work in SQLite console
SELECT printf('%.d', 1234 ) AS val_tot FROM itens;
```

Is this a TFDQuery bug or does it have some configuration for it to work?

Comment: User [CL.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11654/cl) was right with their comment. SQLite statically linked by FireDAC doesn't have the enhanced printf function. That was added in [version 3.18.0](https://sqlite.org/changes.html) whilst e.g. version shipped with Delphi Tokyo is 3.9.2.

Comment: So, at least for now, there is no workaround for this except to adapt my SQL statement to work with Delphi ... Or is there a way to update SQLite from Delphi Tokyo? thanks

Comment: Yes, you can link SQLite dynamically. Follow the [Client Software](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Connect_to_SQLite_database_(FireDAC)#Client_Software) topic, section _Dynamic linking_.

Comment: I've read the article you pointed out and also read the other related articles, but I still could not solve the problem because I can't see how to dynamically point the correct driver on Android and Windows. But I'll study a little bit more to understand the correct operation. Thank you!

Comment: Have you undefined `FireDAC_SQLITE_STATIC` from FireDAC.inc include file? I would suggest making a copy of FireDAC source just for your project. Then you can set `TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.VendorLib` or just add the proper library (sqlite3.dll in 32 or 64 bitness for Windows or libsqlite.so for Android) to your compiled output binary folder.

Comment: Not yet for `FireDAC_SQLITE_STATIC` and I'm just trying to make use of `TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.VendorLib`, which I suppose to be the most appropriate.

Comment: Nope. That won't work. By default is SQLite library statically linked. For making it dynamic you must first undefine that `FireDAC_SQLITE_STATIC` define. And only after that you can link dynamically (which is the `TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.VendorLib` property for). The simplest you can do is making copy of FireDAC source just for your project and modifying FireDAC.inc file in that copy to make SQLite loading dynamic. Then you can setup `TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.VendorLib` of your choice (or just put the library with the binary). This process is confusuing, and could have been easier, I know.. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty confusing. That's why I'm still trying to get it right. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You're welcome! Well, the problem is that one cannot undefine a symbol by runtime code; you cannot undefine a symbol by setting a property value (`VendorLib`) and you cannot conditionally statically link an object other way than using defined symbol. But well, the driver link could have been divided into two separate classes, one for static and one for dynamic linking. But that's a design choice. P.S. if you were having any troubles, feel free to ask me here, or by a new question and I will try to help (I'm monitoring FireDAC tag ;-)

Comment: Very kind of you! I'll try to make it work. I'm with other projects under development and I can't devote more time to solving this problem now. But I'll have to get back to it sometime. Thank you.